# Applying a weight to two numbers in excel

Tags: excel

I have 2 numbers. One is a projected number and the other is a current number. I would like to average them both but apply a lesser weight to the projected number. How does that work is excel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Weighted average formula:

```
 =SUMPRODUCT(B4:D4,B3:D3)/SUM(B4:D4)
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, Thank you!